# Testing and deploying Zurb Foundation apps

Tags: zurb-foundation-apps, html5-apps

[Foundation Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps)

We've been building an app through Foundation's new app feature and all we know is html, css and some javascript. We've basically created a template already and now we've been searching all over the place on how to push this html5 app to our phones for testing. We've tried the localhost:8080 on our phones on the same network and it's just not wanting to work. Even further, how do we deploy to both ios and android stores once we're finished? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your app while running on your Desktop you need to open http://yourcomputername:8080

or resolve your computer via ip
for example:

http:// 192.168.1.2:8080

for deployment as a hybrid app check out phonegap.

If you are thinking about adding user authentication
check out:

https://github.com/webnugget/fapp-stack